# Printing in Java using JPS in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print a JPG image to a printer using JPS following tutorials but it always gives me an error in mac osx. It always says, "Unable to convert PostScript file".

Here is the code I'm using to print:

```
final PrintRequestAttributeSet photoAttr = createPhotoPaperPrintAttributes(copies);
PrintService printerService = findPrintService(photoAttr);
        try {
            DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
            das.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI));
            das.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A6);
            final Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(new FileInputStream(new File(imageFile)), DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG, das);

            DocPrintJob printJob = printerService.createPrintJob();
            printJob.print(doc, photoAttr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new PrintException(e);
        }
```

Does anyone know what might be ging wrong?

I manged to get it to print using a Printable interface but I couln't print the image with a higher resolution than 72 DPI. I tried some suggestions like scaling the graphics 2d but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Running into this now on any mac printing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I did not so I totally abandoned implementation using java printing api. What I did is just use the native printing "lp" and a "CUPS" driver

Answer (score 1):

Using only JPS you will have problems with Mac.
My suggestion is use Java 2 Print API + Java Print Service.

Java 2 Print API is something like 1990 style. To avoid to create your code using Java 2 Print API you could use PDFBox http://pdfbox.apache.org as a framework.

With PDFBox you could create a PDF document (http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/documentcreation.html) but instead of save, print it using that code:

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); 
printJob.setPrintService(service);      
document.silentPrint(printJob);
```

It works fine in my Mac.